# How to prevent access to a web application through a HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, http-headers, httprequest

I have web application which was developed in .NET 3.5, hosted on Windows server.

Outside people are accessing my web application by creating `HttpWebRequest` POSTs and passing the browser information along with necessary input values.

How to restrict access to my web application through `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: You don't want users to use a `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: yes..exactly..people are taking all the browser details like Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 6110
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=eoymdoifmepp5bfjpquomnnr ; by using fiddler application. and changing the actual values of textbox or dropdown value even they are disabled and posting again .

Comment: Are these 'people' logged in users or are they people who should not have access at all?

Comment: yes those people have a login access to the web applcation. but they should not allowed to change the values which are in disabled .

Answer (score 3):

You can't really restricted users from calling your site using `HttpWebRequest` (or 'not a browser', so to say) since all that information about the client machine, like the browser used, can be spoofed.

You have to wonder if you really want to go through all this. Do you want to make your users life miserable (or a least the user experience of your site)? If you do, you might want to use Captchas to make sure there is a real user and not a robot.